# Using JWT for authentication from WCF self hosted seever

Tags: c#, wcf, jwt, wcf-security, wcf-rest

We have a self hosted WCF REST API service (not ASP.Net). We currently support Basic and Negotiate authentication.

We would like to add support for JWT in a cookie, so that we dont have to authenticate against the DB on each call, and so we dont have to set headers. The main issue is that we want our web application, which uses the API to be able to provide links to retrieve resources for downloading without setting headers, ie rely on browser having a JWT pushed into a cookie.

We have an endpoint called /API/AuthToken, which supports Basic Authentication, but we’re not sure what the code to generate a JWT token, and pushing it to a cookie would look like. Specifically, what does the code for generating a JWT token should do.
I have not been able to find any documentation or samples on how to do this? Any leads or code snippets?

Comment: IIRC you can get the cookies by inspecting OperationContext.Current and then go over the MessageProperties (not Messageheaders). The properties should have the HttpHeaders which you can then inspect.

Comment: Thanks! That part we understand, its more about what the endpoint that would set the cookie with the JWT token would look like.

Comment: The same. You set the cookie with the JWT token on the outgoing MessageProperties